# How to convert a generator to a Pytorch Dataloader?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a generator that creates synthetic data. How can I convert this into a PyTorch dataloader?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap your generator with a [`data.IterableDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):

```
class IterDataset(data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.generator = generator

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.generator()
```

Naturally, you can then wrap this dataset with a [`data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader).

Here is a minimal example showing its use:

```
>>> gen = lambda: [(yield x) for x in range(10)]

>>> dataset = IterDataset(gen)
>>> for i in data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2):
...    print(i)
tensor([0, 1])
tensor([2, 3])
tensor([4, 5])
tensor([6, 7])
tensor([8, 9])
```

Comment: If I do this with an infinite generator, will the dataset/dataloader have any notion of an epoch? Or will the training loop run forever?

Comment: No it won't have any notion length since `data.IterableDataset` doesn't implement a `__len__` function.

Comment: The proposed solution did not work for me. I get constantly this error: TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Comment: Did you replicate the code from above? Can you provide your code?

Comment: It should be `return self.generator` (without parenthesis) in `__iter__`, otherwise I also get `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3):

With the limited information that you provide, this is the simplest solution (I assume that your generator creates images from noise such as the [original gans](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661)):

```py
import torch

def get_data(batch_size, generator, latent_dim=512):
    z = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_dim)
    return genenerator(z)

def dataloader(batch_size, generator, iteration, latent_dim=512):
    for i in range(iteration):
        yield(get_data(batch_size, generator, latent_dim))

batch_size = 64
generator = GANs(...)
iteration = 100
latent_dim = 512

loader = dataloader(batch_size, generator, iteration, latent_dim)
for images in loader:
    # do something
```

Comment: I more meant a Pytorch dataloader, not a generic function named dataloader. My apologies for not being more specific!